# Ask for Int value in any of my columns from my Table

Tags: sql, procedure

Lets say i have a table named 'Test' with these columns and values

```
ID  Apple Pear Pineapple Orange
1    2     3    4         4
2    1     12   1         0
```

Now I want to make a `SELECT` statement to return all the rows where there is a value of 4 in any column.

I could do it like this, but I have many columns to check, so I need to find a other way to do this.

```
SELECT * FROM Test
WHERE test.apple = 4 or test.apple = 4 or test.pineapple = 4 or test.pineapple = 4
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Test
WHERE 4 IN (Apple, Pear, Pineapple, Orange)
```

Answer (score 0):

One method is to use `in`:

```
select t.*
from test t
where 4 in (t.apple, t.pear, t.pineapple, t.orange);
```

You still need to list the columns, but they just go in the `in` list.